# Render Number, Bool, String as String fails in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a small program, that takes any one of Boolean, Number, String and renders it as a String.

```
module Main () where

data Value = Number Int
       | Bool Bool
       | String String
    deriving (Eq, Show)

renderValue :: Value -> String
renderValue (String s) = show s
renderValue(Bool True) = "true"
renderValue(Number n) = show n

main = do
  putStrLn $ renderValue "bye, saravana"
```

renderValue is an overloaded method that is supposed to take String inputs. But the last line,

```
putStrLn $ renderValue "bye, saravana"
```

prints error as,

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Value’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
In the first argument of ‘renderValue’, namely ‘"bye, saravana"’
In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
  ‘renderValue "bye, saravana"’
In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn $ renderValue "bye, saravana"
```

Why is `Value = Number | Bool | String` not taking string inputs?

Comment: `renderValue` requires a `Value` argument while you are trying to provide a `String` (which is an alias of `[Char]`). You need to use `renderValue (String "bye, saravana")`.

Comment: @Lee You should post that as an answer.

Comment: i tried this, `renderValue([Char] s) = show s`. It fails with `parse error on [Char]`. Then, i tried `import Data.Char` and `renderValue(Char s:xs) = show s`. It still complains, `Not in scope: data constructor 'Char'`....

Answer (score 4):

Your `data` declaration defines a type `Value` along with three constructors: `Number`, `Bool` and `String`. Your `renderValue` function requires a `Value` argument, while in

```
renderValue "bye, saravana"
```

you are providing a `String` (which is an alias for `[Char]`) argument. You need to provide a `Value` i.e.

```
renderValue (String "bye, saravana")
```

you should also consider renaming your constructors for `Value` since they clash with the existing `String` and `Bool` types which may be causing some confusion.

Comment: Why does n't haskell interpret "bye, saravana" s type as String, and call the right implementation. isn't explicit casting of a String constant as String, redundant?

Comment: @MadhavanKumar - In `renderValue` you aren't casting, you are matching on the named constructors `Number`, `String`, `Bool`. Those constructors also define functions to create `Value` values e.g. `Number` is a function `Int -> Value`. You aren't creating a type which can be either an `Int`, `String` or `Bool` you are creating a type with three cases which contain an `Int`, `String` or `Bool`. I suggest you rename you constructors to `VString`, `VNumber` and `VBool` which may make things clearer.

Answer (score -1):

1. Note that you don't need to use `show` in the `String` case since it already has the right type.
2. No need to derive `Show` and `Eq` if you don't use them.
3. Your code doesn't define a case for `Bool False` (verify by compiling with `-Wall`), you can reuse the `Show` instance of `Bool` to handle `False` and `True` at the same time.

Here's the code:

```
module Main where

import Data.Char

data Value = Number Int
           | Bool Bool
           | String String

renderValue :: Value -> String
renderValue (String s) = s
renderValue (Bool b)   = toLower <$> show b
renderValue (Number n) = show n

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ renderValue $ String "bye, saravana"
```

Alternatively, you can use the `OverloadedStrings` extension if you want to avoid typing `String`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import Data.Char
import Data.String

data Value = Number Int
           | Bool Bool
           | String String

instance IsString Value where
  fromString = String

renderValue :: Value -> String
renderValue (String s) = s
renderValue (Bool b)   = toLower <$> show b
renderValue (Number n) = show n

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ renderValue "bye, saravana"
```